# Computing $\iint \sin(4x^2 +2y^2)\, \mathrm dA$ over an elliptical region

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

$$\iint \sin(4x^2 +2y^2)dA,$$ where the region is bounded by ellipse $4x^2 + 2y^2 = \pi$ and the lines $y = 0$ and $y = \sqrt{2}x$.

This looks like a change of variables integral. Need some hints. 
You guys are right. **say region is also bounded by first quadrant.**

Here is what I did:

ok you must make change of variables u= 2x and v = root(2)* y which makes ellipse transform to circle with radius root(pi), compute jacobian d(x,y)/d(u,v) which is equal to 1/(2*root(2)). y=0 implies v=0. other line implies v=u.

thus using polar coordinates, region is a circle with radius rootpi. angle from 0 to pi/4 then compute integral. sin(4x^2+2y^2) implies sin(u^2+v^2)= sin(r^2).  theta is from 0 to pi/4 and r from 0 to root(pi).

I got pi*root(2)/8. Anyone disagree? I dont think so. I'm out.Peace.

"btw ill check mark for anyone who writes my answer properly."

Comment: Maybe let $y=\sqrt{2}\,z$, then polar coordinates. Or go directly to polar.

Comment: I'm not sure what is $\,A\,$: the ellipse is a veritcal one, with big vertical radius $\,\sqrt{\pi/2}\,$ and small horizontal radius $\,\sqrt \pi/2\,$ , and this ellipse get's crossed by the line $\,y=\sqrt 2\,x\,$ , so...what is the region, then? Between the ellipse and above the line, or below the line...or somewhere else?

Comment: (and, I'm assuming it's the smaller region between those two lines.)

Comment: please make your titles refelect the question, they end up as side links, have a look at side links and you know which title was chosen well or not

Comment: That's my point, @mathlover: which one of both bounded regions between the ellipse and that line is $\,A\,$?!

Comment: Thus the whole ellipse, @mathlover? What then do we need the line for?!

Comment: check above post again

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you ever see the requirement to integrate over an ellipse, it is oftentimes best to use the Jacobian to change this to a circle, and use the adjusted polar coordinates.

Your ellipse is:
$$\frac{x^2}{\left(\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}\right)^2} + \frac{y^2}{\left(\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{\sqrt{2}}\right)^2} = 1$$

Now, we let:

$$x = \left(\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}\right)r \cos\theta$$
$$y = \left(\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{\sqrt{2}}\right)r \sin\theta$$

The Jacobian is:
$$J = \left[\begin{array}{cc}
\frac{\partial x}{\partial r} & \frac{\partial x}{\partial \theta}\\
\frac{\partial y}{\partial r} & \frac{\partial y}{\partial \theta}\\
\end{array}\right] = 
\left[\begin{array}{cc}
\left(\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}\right)\cos\theta & -\left(\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}\right)r \sin\theta\\
\left(\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{\sqrt{2}}\right)\sin\theta & \left(\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{\sqrt{2}}\right)r \cos\theta\\
\end{array}\right] $$

The determinant is:
$$\begin{align}
\det J &= \left(\left(\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}\right)\cos\theta \cdot \left(\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{\sqrt{2}}\right)r \cos\theta\right) - \left(-\left(\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}\right)r \sin\theta \cdot \left(\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{\sqrt{2}}\right)\sin\theta\right) \\
&= r\frac{\sqrt2\pi}{4}\left(\sin^2\theta + \cos^2\theta\right) \\
&= r\frac{\sqrt2\pi}{4}
\end{align}$$

To find the "difficult" bound:
$$y = \sqrt{2} x$$
$$\left(\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{\sqrt{2}}\right)r \sin\theta = \sqrt{2} \left(\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}\right)r \cos\theta$$
$$\tan{\theta} = 1\implies \theta = \frac{\pi}{4}$$

So, in our "new coordinate system," our bounds are $0\le \theta \le \frac{\pi}{4}$, $0 \le r \le 1$.

Thus, after the substitution, we have:

$$\int_0^\frac{\pi}{4}\int_0^1\sin(\pi r^2)\det J \; dr\; d\theta$$
$$\int_0^\frac{\pi}{4}\int_0^1\left(\sin(\pi r^2)\right)\left(r\frac{\sqrt2\pi}{4}\right) \; dr\; d\theta$$

And I'm sure you can solve the above (hint: $u$-substitution).

EDIT: I only set this integral up for the region in the first quadrant.  The work done for finding the Jacobian is the same for both regions (the first quadrant and the third quadrant), so all the OP needs to do to solve his/her problem is to set up a similar integral (using the same substitutions) over the second part of the region.

It should be noted that I checked absolutely none of the above after calculating the Jacobian, and I was taking some pretty far mental leaps at the very end.  Thus, I highly suggest that you take this just as some guidance, rather than me working the whole problem out for you, as there might be some mistakes in it.

Comment: But what "original" region $\,A\,$ did you choose?! Read the comments below the question...

Comment: @DonAntonio Yeah... I just read those now.  The Jacobian work should not change regardless of the region chosen.  I chose the region in the first quadrant of the x-y plane to set up the double integral at the end.  Since it appears the OP wants the regions in the first and third quadrants, all s/he needs to do is to add another integral from $\pi \le \theta \le \text{whatever the other limit is}$.

Comment: @DonAntonio Wow.  Envisioning it in my mind now, the entire ellipse is "bounded" by those lines, but broken into 4 pieces.  (It's amazing how one can think in only one way for so long...)  Anyway, my region for $A$ that I evaluated is the one *fully contained* in the first quadrant.

Comment: @mathlover what's the matter with my answer? (Just noticed the "accept" and "unaccept")

Comment: See how i did it.

Comment: @mathlover I did your substitution and the change to polar in one step by the way I constructed my substitution.