# Double Integral Over a General Region

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

Evaluate the $\iint_R \sin\left(\frac{(x+y)}{2}\right)\cos\left(\frac{(x-y)}{2}\right) dA$ where R is a triangle with vertices $(0,0), (2,0), (1,1)$ using $u = \frac{(x+y)}{2}$ and $v = \frac{(x-y)}{2}$

I had trouble performing the substitution because I was not sure how to find $du$ or $dv$ or if I even needed to to perform the substitution.

Sorry for my poor formatting and any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 2):

Here is how to find the equations for the new region.

The segment connecting the points $(0,0)$ and $(1,1)$ has equation: $y = x$. So this gives:

$x - y = 0$ and so: $v = \dfrac{x-y}{2} = 0$.

The segment connecting the points $(1,1)$ and $(2,0)$ has equation: $x + y = 2$. So:

$u = \dfrac{x+y}{2} = 1$,

and finally the segment connecting the points $(0,0)$ and $(2,0)$ has equation: $y = 0$.

So: $u - v = \dfrac{x+y}{2} - \dfrac{x-y}{2} = y = 0$. In summary your new region is defined in the $u$-$v$ coordinates are:

$v = 0$, $u = 1$, and $u = v$.

Answer (score 1):

The technique you need to use isn't as directly related to $u$-substitution as you may be thinking.  Instead, you are supposed to calculate the [Jacobian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobian_matrix_and_determinant) of the change of variables.

Specifically, you want to compute:
$$J = \det\pmatrix{\frac{\partial x}{\partial u} & \frac{\partial x}{\partial v}\\\frac{\partial y}{\partial u} & \frac{\partial y}{\partial v}}$$

Then, your integral becomes
$$\iint_G \sin\left(u\right)\cos\left(v\right) |J|dA$$
(Where $G$ is the appropriate transformation of $R$ under the new variables -- see $8\pi r$'s answer for more information regarding that.)

Let me know if you need more guidance.

Comment: See also [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/440183/23353)

Comment: For a step-by-step solution I've written up on Jacobians before, see [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/325122/23353)